# Can I make an iterator with a simple function? (No generator or Symbol.iterator)

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable

I have been trying to make an iterator using a plain function, without a generator or using the `Symbol.iterator` protocol for academic purposes. For that, I have made a function that returns an object with a `next` parameter, but trying to run it as the `iterable` argument of an `for...of` loop yields unwanted results.

Here is my code so far, which I copied from the [Iterators and Generators page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

```
function iterateThis(arr){
    let i = 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            return i < arr.length ?
                {value: arr[i++], done: false} :
                {done: true};
        }
     };
}
```

If I try to run it like so:

```
const iterable = iterateThis([1,2,3,4,5]);
for(item in iterable){
    console.log(item);
}
```

On the console, I just get a single result: `next`.

Am I doing something wrong in the creation of the function `iterateThis`? Or is `for...of` only designed to work with generators and the `Symbol.iterator` property?

Executed on Node v8.11.1

Comment: iterator objects are built with a special structure that allows them to be iterated over using `for-in`. If you don't apply iterator logic through the iterator common symbol I don't see how it would be possible at any level to duplicate the effect. It's outside of native functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your `iterateThis` function returns an *iterator* but the `for/of` construct expects a *iterable*.

**Okay, wait, whats the difference?**

From [MDN's page on iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols):

> In order to be **iterable**, an object must implement the `@@iterator`
>   method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its
>   prototype chain) must have a property with a `@@iterator` key which is
>   available via constant `Symbol.iterator`:

On the other hand:

> An object is an **iterator** when it implements a `next()` method with the
>   following semantics: *Ommited due to length, TL;DR: The next method
>   returns an object of the form: `{value: T, done: boolean}`*

They are related in that calling the `@@iterator` method of an *iterable* returns an *iterator*.

The `for/of` loop always expects an iterable, so if you want to use `for/of`, you have to use `@@iterator`/`Symbol.iterator`. There's just no way around it as far as I know. But your snippet can be easily modified to use it by just creating an object that returns your iterator when it's `Symbol.iterator` method is called:

```js
function iterateThis(arr){
    let i = 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            return i < arr.length ?
                {value: arr[i++], done: false} :
                {done: true};
        }
     };
}

function makeIterableFromIterator(iterator) {
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]: function() {
      return iterator;
    }
  }
}

const iterator = iterateThis([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
const iterable = makeIterableFromIterator(iterator);

for (item of iterable) {
  console.log(item);
}
```