# Do Generators return both an iterator and an iterable?

Tags: javascript, iterator, iterable

From [this question I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917742/can-i-make-an-iterator-with-a-simple-function-no-generator-or-symbol-iterator) I learned that `for...of` expects an iterable, which is

> an object that implements the `@@iterable` method, meaning that the object (or one of the objects up its prototype chain) must have a property with a `@@iterator` key which is available via constant `Symbol.iterator`

So, an iterable would look something like this:

```
const iterableObject: {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function someIteratorFunction() {
    //...
  }
}
```

On the other hand we have generators, which look like this:

```
function* generatorFoo(){
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
}
```

And can be used in `for...of` constructs like this:

```
for(const item of generatorFoo())
  console.log(item);
```

So, calling `generatorFoo()` returns an iterable since `for...of` has no problem dealing with it. I can also call `generatorFoo()[Symbol.iterator]()` and receive an iterator, to confirm this.

However, calling `generatorFoo` would also return an iterator since I can call `generatorFoo()` I get an object with a method `next` to get the next value of the iterator, like so:

```
const iteratorFromGen = generatorFoo();
iteratorFromGen.next().value; //1
iteratorFromGen.next().value; //2
iteratorFromGen.next().value; //3
iteratorFromGen.next().value; //4
```

Does this mean that calling a generator function returns an object that has access to a `next` method *and* a `[Symbol.iterator]` method?

When calling a generator function, do we get an object that is both an iterator and an iterable? How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes, a generator is both an iterable and an iterator.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

> The Generator object is returned by a generator function and it
>   conforms to both the iterable protocol and the iterator protocol.

The iterator returned by calling the `Symbol.iterator` method of the returned generator object is the same as the generator object itself. For example:

```js
function* gen() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10) yield i++;
}

const iterableIterator = gen();
console.log(iterableIterator === iterableIterator[Symbol.iterator]()); // true
```

You can even replicate that pattern pretty easily by conforming to the iterator protocol, and having a `Symbol.iterator` method that returns `this`. So for example:

```js
class MyIterableIterator {
  
  constructor(arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.i = 0;
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this;
  }
  
  next() {
    if (this.i === this.arr.length) return {done: true}
    return {value: this.arr[this.i++], done: false}
  }
}

const iterableIterator = new MyIterableIterator([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(iterableIterator === iterableIterator[Symbol.iterator]()); // true

// Works fine if you call next manually, or using a for-of loop.
console.log(iterableIterator.next())
for (let item of iterableIterator) {
  console.log(item);
}
```